# I want to redirect the execv of ls in a file and then in a pipe, why is not working?

Tags: c, pipe, ls, execv

First of all, I want to redirect the output of ls (exec) in a file and then from a file to pipe, why is not working? It's ok when I redirect in a file, but that's all.

How can I do to find the length of the output of `ls`? (that's why I did a redirect to a file).

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char input[]="ls",ch, delim[]=" ",*result,aux[2000],*user=NULL,*password=NULL,aux1[2000],aux2[2000],aux3[2000],aux4[2000],*arg[1000];
    int p1[2],p2[2],i,j,len,nrRead,ok,log,f;
    pid_t pid,pidd;
    pid=fork(); f=open("alice.txt",O_RDWR|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT,0700);

    if(pid == 0){
        i=0; 
        printf("f: %d",f);
        if(strlen(input) == 2) {arg[0]="ls";arg[1]=NULL; i=2;}
        else 
        {       
            result=strtok(input,delim);
            arg[i++]=result;
            result=strtok(NULL,delim);
            while(result!= NULL)
            {
                printf("LS --- 5\n");
                arg[i++]=result;
                result=strtok(NULL,delim);
            }
            arg[i]=NULL;
        }

        close (1);

        if (dup2(f,1) == -1)    
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "dup - 1\n");
            exit (9);
        }

        if( 0 == (pidd=fork())) { 
            execvp("ls",arg);
        }

        close(f);
        i=0;
        while(0 != read(1,&ch,sizeof(char)))
        { 
            aux4[i]=ch;
            i++;
        }
        aux4[i]='\0';

        close(1);
        if (dup2(p2[1],1) == -1)    
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "dup - 1\n");
            exit (9);
        }
        //close(p2[1]);
        len=strlen(aux4);
        //printf("LUNG: %d",len);
        write(1,&len, sizeof(4));       
        return 0;
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        close(p2[1]);
        read(p2[0],&len,sizeof(int));
        printf("pp: %d",len);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fork`ing and `dup`ing yourself you can conveniently use `popen` to do what you want. If you really need to know the size of the output beforehand, you don't need to redirect to a file, you can simply count the bytes you can read from the pipe before you hit `EOF`. Example (no error checking):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fd;
    char *buf;
    size_t size; /* counter for output size */

    fd = popen("ls", "r"); /* open a pipe running ls for reading ("r") */

    size = 0;
    while (fgetc(fd) != EOF) {
        size++;
    }

    pclose(fd);

    printf("Output is %d bytes\n", size);

    fd = popen("ls", "r");

    buf = malloc(size+1);

    while (fgets(buf, size, fd)) {
        fputs(buf, stdout); /* do what you want here */
    }

    pclose(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you intend to parse the `ls` output later to find files or directories, you are much better off using the `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir` functions on Unix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I need to use fork si exec to my homework, but this idea is ok, too. :)

Comment: well, if `exec` was a requirement, then this solution does not help, obviously. I was just pointing out how I would solve this problem "in production" - actually using exec makes sense for homework or the like, but I wouldn't use here it if I don't have to.